# How do I copy selected paths of a shape in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, mac, cs6

I was wondering how I copy selected paths of a shape in PS CS6.

- I start selecting the paths I want to copy by clicking on them and holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.
- I then press <kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd></kbd> which only copies **one** of the selected paths.

How can I copy all of the selected paths, not just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the paths as you normally would using <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click with the black arrow path tool, then <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd></kbd>  to copy and <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd></kbd> to paste. There's no need to use any other modifier keys.

If you want to copy multiple paths within the shape layer by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-dragging, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, start to drag, *then* add <kbd>Shift</kbd> to constrain the movement.

Comment: Wonderfully easy. I didn't realise that I was trying to do this with the white arrow path tool... thanks so much! Nearly went crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I find it's much easier to duplicate the path in the Paths Panel, then delete the parts I do not want in the duplicate.